# WinForm button background image updates only every other run

Tags: c#, winforms, image

I want a blinking LED -- alternately a lighted, then a dark image in a PictureBox -- to appear during a run (that I click a button to start).  The image lights when the run starts, and goes dark when it the run finishes.  That always works.

This code:

```
this.timer.SynchronizingObject = this;
this.timer.Interval = 250;
this.timer.Elapsed += (s, ea) =>
{
    this.ledLit = !this.ledLit;
    ShowInLog(this.ledLit ? "/" : "\\");
    this.picMarking.BackgroundImage = this.ledLit ? this.imageStopped : this.imageRunning;
    this.picMarking.Refresh();
};
```

works great to show a blinking LED image during the run...every other run.

On every even-numbered invocation, the display of alternating slashes shows that the timer is working, but the background image does not update (except perhaps a rare flicker).

Why?  How do I make it to work on every invocation?

Comment: First you say that: "The image lights when the run starts, and goes dark when it the run finishes. That always works." And then you say: "works great to show a blinking LED image during the run...every other run." These two statements don't seem to go together, can you be a little more clear?

Comment: At the start of the run, I set the image to lighted.  That works.  At the end of the run, I set the image to dark. That works.  On odd runs, the images alternate when the timer fires.  On even runs, the images do NOT alternate, but remain lighted (until it finishes).

Answer (score 0):

Here's some quick code I put together for your "blinking" effect:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Blinker
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Interval = 250;
            timer1.Tick += timer1_Tick;
            timer1.Start();
        }

        void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Tick");
            pictureBox1.BackColor = (pictureBox1.BackColor == System.Drawing.Color.Red) ? System.Drawing.Color.Black : System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
    }
}
```

I've used event handlers for the Tick event on the timer to trigger the blinking. You can adjust the image like I have with the BackColor property. It's a quick and dirty approach, but it gets the blinking effect achieved.

Comment: The code I have is very similar, and works to achieve a blinking effect.  What does not make sense is why is works only for odd-numbered invocations.  How does your code explain that?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my problem here: [Custom event handler is repeating itself...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17801610/custom-event-handler-is-repeating-itself)

My problem is that I subscribed to the tick event each time, rather than only once.